# mpeg-dash playback on ios

Tags: ffmpeg, ios, mpeg-dash

I have created my dash videos with mp4box and ffmpeg. it plays fine on exo player and videoJS on android and all browsers, but it doesn't play on ios 10 safari. how can I make it playable on ios and safari?

here is a demo:

http://79.175.133.185/static/videos/bighero/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Dash will not playback on iOS safari. You can create an HLS manifest however and reuse the same dash assets and play that.

Comment: as far as i know it should be able to play on ios 10+ @SlimSCSI

Comment: The assets, yes, the manifest, no. You need an HLS (m3u8) manifest.

Comment: you mean I should create a m3u8 manifest with my dash segments? how can i do this? could you explain more?

Comment: you can create a manifest with any text editor, and the specification is available on apples website, or the pantos document (google it)